# Android List + Adapter shows only first entry

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

So I've made a custom ArrayAdapter to populate my Lists, which just overrides getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent).

If I use it like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Everthing works fine and my List is correctly displayed with all entries.

Now if I try to use the same Adapter Class on a < ListView/> in a XML Layout, like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
MyAdapter a = new MyAdapter (lv.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, entries);
lv.setAdapter(a);
```

it shows only the first entry of the List.

I already tried adding the items manually with adapter.add(entry.get(i)); and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); afterwards which didn't help.

e: Here's the XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bc_path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bc_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:background="@drawable/title_gradient"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bc_genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/location_gradient"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.4"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/bc_homepage"
            android:src="@drawable/homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:onClick="loadWebsite"
            android:background="@drawable/black_button"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            />
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/bc_facebook"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:onClick="loadWebsite"
            android:background="@drawable/black_button"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            />
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/bc_myspace"
            android:src="@drawable/myspace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:onClick="loadWebsite"
            android:background="@drawable/black_button"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            />
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/bc_fav"
            android:src="@drawable/d_attends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:onClick="favBand"
            android:background="@drawable/black_button"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you implement `getCount` as `return 1`?

Comment: ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list); What is this **v.** in the above code ??

Comment: can you paste the XML for the list? it may be an issue of layout size

Comment: No I don't override getCount and it returns the right number of entries.

Comment: In the onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) of my ArrayListFragment it's View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_layout, container, false);

Comment: don't put a listview in a scrollview. that does not work

Comment: That was in fact the Problem, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should not use ListView inside your scrollView as ListView inbuilt provides scrolling feature. In the above code , your ListView is coming at the bottom due to vertically adding all views inside Linear Layout so as root is ScrollView, List view's auto scroll view option is not able to show you all entries. Just give a thought for this and try adding ListView outside ScrollView.